# How to use pd.read_html() to extract table data from a website without error in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

### I have created a program that collects table data at the following location. And when extracting data in soup library, it appears fine, but when converting html codes to a table using pandas library pd.read_html(table) I get an error message, I don't know why

***this code bellow :***

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

header = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36'
}

url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries"
req = requests.get(url, headers=header)

#test of response server (permession for client)
""" True response with 200 and not forbiden access """

#soup methode : extract data finded in html page from the link
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'lxml')
tables = soup.find('table',{'id':'main_table_countries_today'})
df = pd.read_html(tables)
print(df)
```

***after excute :***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\pc\Desktop\manual scrape\scrape 1\covid find all data.py", line 18, in <module>
    df = pd.read_html(tables)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1085, in read_html
    return _parse(
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 893, in _parse
    tables = p.parse_tables()
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 213, in parse_tables
    tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 717, in _build_doc
    r = parse(self.io, parser=parser)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 939, in parse
    return etree.parse(filename_or_url, parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3521, in lxml.etree.parse
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1875, in lxml.etree._parseDocument
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
PS C:\Users\pc\Desktop\manual scrape\scrape 1>
```

---

***The program aims to print table data at code execution time using `pd.read_html()`
Such as :***

[this table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt91V.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the `soup` to string before passing in into `.read_html()`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"
}

url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries"
req = requests.get(url, headers=header)

# test of response server (permession for client)
""" True response with 200 and not forbiden access """

# soup methode : extract data finded in html page from the link
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
tables = soup.find("table", {"id": "main_table_countries_today"})
df = pd.read_html(str(tables).upper())[0]  # <-- convert the soup to str first
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         #           COUNTRY,OTHER  TOTALCASES  NEWCASES  TOTALDEATHS  NEWDEATHS  TOTALRECOVERED  NEWRECOVERED  ACTIVECASES  SERIOUS,CRITICAL  TOT CASES/1M POP  DEATHS/1M POP   TOTALTESTS  TESTS/ 1M POP    POPULATION          CONTINENT  1 CASEEVERY X PPL  1 DEATHEVERY X PPL  1 TESTEVERY X PPL  NEW CASES/1M POP  NEW DEATHS/1M POP  ACTIVE CASES/1M POP
0      NaN           NORTH AMERICA    48516635  142956.0    1000760.0     2587.0      37927770.0       60945.0    9588105.0           32950.0               NaN            NaN          NaN            NaN           NaN      NORTH AMERICA                NaN                 NaN                NaN               NaN                NaN                  NaN
1      NaN                    ASIA    70629576  250387.0    1043218.0     3825.0      65875219.0      257280.0    3711139.0           40409.0               NaN            NaN          NaN            NaN           NaN               ASIA                NaN                 NaN                NaN               NaN                NaN                  NaN
2      NaN           SOUTH AMERICA    36987244   27316.0    1132455.0      757.0      34786052.0        1198.0    1068737.0           15195.0               NaN            NaN          NaN            NaN           NaN      SOUTH AMERICA                NaN                 NaN                NaN               NaN                NaN                  NaN
3      NaN                  EUROPE    55607330  135394.0    1176585.0     1575.0      50739008.0      129944.0    3691737.0           11644.0               NaN            NaN          NaN            NaN           NaN             EUROPE                NaN                 NaN                NaN               NaN                NaN                  NaN
4      NaN                  AFRICA     7902675   11584.0     197645.0      305.0       7027951.0       16775.0     677079.0            4464.0               NaN            NaN          NaN            NaN           NaN             AFRICA                NaN                 NaN                NaN               NaN                NaN                  NaN
5      NaN                 OCEANIA      166231    1768.0       2196.0        8.0        118215.0        1108.0      45820.0             237.0               NaN            NaN          NaN            NaN           NaN  AUSTRALIA/OCEANIA                NaN                 NaN                NaN               NaN                NaN                  NaN
6      NaN                     NaN         721       NaN         15.0        NaN           706.0           NaN          0.0               0.0               NaN            NaN          NaN            NaN           NaN                NaN                NaN                 NaN                NaN               NaN                NaN                  NaN
7      NaN                   WORLD   219810412  569405.0    4552874.0     9057.0     196474921.0      467250.0   18782617.0          104899.0           28200.0          584.1          NaN            NaN           NaN                ALL                NaN                 NaN                NaN               NaN                NaN                  NaN
8      1.0                     USA    40449279  115125.0     661200.0     1237.0      31175601.0       37665.0    8612478.0           25675.0          121372.0         1984.0  588098779.0      1764643.0  3.332678e+08      NORTH AMERICA                8.0               504.0                1.0            345.00               4.00              25843.0
9      2.0                   INDIA    32902293   45430.0     439900.0      341.0      32056062.0       34965.0     406331.0            8944.0           23572.0          315.0  524868734.0       376027.0  1.395828e+09               ASIA               42.0              3173.0                3.0             33.00               0.20                291.0
10     3.0                  BRAZIL    20830495   26280.0     581914.0      686.0      19775873.0           NaN     472708.0            8318.0           97192.0         2715.0   56897224.0       265475.0  2.143224e+08      SOUTH AMERICA               10.0               368.0                4.0            123.00               3.00               2206.0
11     4.0                  RUSSIA     6956318   18985.0     184812.0      798.0       6218048.0       18669.0     553458.0            2300.0           47644.0         1266.0  179500000.0      1229389.0  1.460075e+08             EUROPE               21.0               790.0                1.0            130.00               5.00               3791.0

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you , But why doesn't it print all the data, why does it only display a few knowing the table is long?

Comment: @danielmalten It prints 238 rows, isn't it all?

Comment: At execution time, the execution only prints a few portion of 238.
Only 10 of them appear
I don't know what's the problem

Comment: @danielmalten It might depend where you run the script and how do you show the results (in Jupiter? Maybe it's configured to show only first 10 rows of dataframe...)

Comment: I just converted the table to a csv file and captured all 238 rows. Perhaps the program at the time of execution takes up limited space from the computer's temporary memory, that's why it does not show all the data at the time of execution